# what does this generic syntax mean?

Tags: java, generics

```
public final class ImmutableList<E> {

    public final E head;
    public final ImmutableList<E> tail;

    public ImmutableList() {
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
    }

    private ImmutableList(E head, ImmutableList<E> tail) {
        this.head = head;
        this.tail = tail;
    }
```

I know that `public final E head`  is declaring an attribute from the generic tip `E` , this syntax is familiar to me but what does this `public final ImmutableList<E> tail;` mean, why declaring this attribute using the name of the generic class and what's the difference between :

```
public final E head;
```

and this :

```
public final ImmutableList<E> tail;
```

are they similar ?

Comment: What would this mean: `class A { private final A obj; }`?

Comment: why not using public final E tail istead of ImmutableList<E> Tail !!

Comment: That would not form a `LinkedList`, which is what this code is supposed to represent I would guess.

Comment: no the goal of the code to not use List and LinkedList to improve performance

Answer (score 1):

This code is a typical implementation of a recursive list. Each list has a head of type E, and as tail another recursive list which also has a head of type E, and as tail yet another recursive list.

The problem with recursion is that to understand it you have to understand recursion first.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the former defines exactly one object of a type E named head. The latter defines an ImmutableList containing a bunch of objects E named tail. This is a recursive definition.